# Accessing or passing variables outside ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this code and i realize that i cant have access outside from ajax except I globalize the data variable. Eg

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'includes/ajax_chart.php',
    data:{present:'present'},
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (data) {
        if (!data.error) {
            b = data;                      
        }   
    }
});
```

So we must work with global variables and data or there is another way to keep these variables inside the function that contains Ajax?

Comment: why dont you return the data value? to variable `b`

Comment: Create a var outside ajax and give the value in success. I don't know if there is another solution

Comment: @Jean-maximeBouloc — That's what they are doing. It doesn't work.

Comment: I tried and return the variable and create var b; outside of the ajax without effect.